# How to use 的 in Chinese?

Tags: meaning, usage, dictionary

I'm recently studying the most frequently used Chinese characters list, and 的 is the #1 in the list, which means it is the MOST USED character in Chinese! So my question is how to use 的 in Chinese? Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [的-地-得, when do you use which?](http://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/89/%e7%9a%84-%e5%9c%b0-%e5%be%97-when-do-you-use-which)

Answer (score 2):

I think there are mainly three cases for 的 in Chinese:

1. Suffix to make personal pronoun
   E.G. 我的，mine or my, it's placed behind 我, that is I, to make 我的， that is MY or MINE.
   Similar case like 他的 for his,她的 for her, 我们的 for ours.
2. As a modal
   It means nothing but emphasize the feeling or state. E.G 好的 good,不是的 not at all,特别的 special.
3. As connection word between adjective and noun.
   E.G. A beautiful girl, 一个美丽的女孩，here 的 is between 美丽 and 女孩， 美丽 is both a adjective and noun in Chinese, but in this sentence it makes adjunct word before 女孩.