# Why is 得 in 多得做不完?

Tags: grammar, sentence-structure, particles

My understanding of 的-地-得 is the same as what's here: [的-地-得, when do you use which?](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/89/%E7%9A%84-%E5%9C%B0-%E5%BE%97-when-do-you-use-which) -- which is summarised as: “地” usually appears before the verb while “得” appears after the verb.

However, I found a sentence which I found very curious in its structure, it doesn't follow these rules. I couldn't find an explanation as to why. The sentence is as follows:

> 不是运动得太少，是事儿太多，**多得做不完**，哪有时间运动？

In `多得做不完`, “得” doesn't follow a verb. Is this an uncommon usage, or is this simply incorrect usage?

Can anybody shed some light on this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is a correct, and common usage.

得 can be also used after an adj to complement its degree/level, similar as the case following a verb. Such as:

> 她红得发紫

So the usage of 得 should be **verb/adj + 得 + complement**.

reference here:http://wenku.baidu.com/view/3ce1a977a417866fb84a8eca.html

Comment: Thank you very much :) Is this "after an adjective" type of usage very common, do you know?

Comment: @Ming AFAIK, yes, It's a common usage.

Comment: I like the completeness of 得 usage in @Stan's answer, however your answer is very straight-forward and answers the questions I raised exactly. Thank you :)

Answer (score 4):

Just share a source on zdic.net. As an auxiliary word, 得 generally has three functions. And in the question, it is **case 3**.

#### [得 as an auxiliary word](http://www.zdic.net/z/19/xs/5F97.htm)

> 得 de
>
> 1. 用在动词后面，表示能够或可以。如：我们可粗心不得。她能去我为什么去不得。
>
>    > **After a verb, means "be able to", "can".**
>    >
>    > "我们可粗心不得" == "我们可 不得(能) 粗心" ***We can't (shouldn't) be careless.***
>    >
>    > "她能去，我为什么去不得" == "她能去，我为什么不能去" ***She can go, why can't I?***
> 2. 用在动词和补语中间，表示可能。如：我拿得动。那办得到。
>
>    > **Between a verb and a complement, means "possible to do", "can".**
>    >
>    > "我拿得动" ***I can bring it.***
>    >
>    > "那办得到" ***That can be done.***
> 3. 用在动词或形容词后面，连接表示程度或结果的补语。如：我冷得打哆嗦。我笑得肚子痛。
>
>    > **After a verb or an adjective, links a complement indicating "degree/extent" or "result".**
>    >
>    > "我冷得打哆嗦" (Literally) ***I feel cold so that I am trembling.***
>    >
>    > "我笑得肚子痛" ***I'm laughing myself to stomachache.*** (= die laughing)

Comment: Thanks, I like the 冷 example in case 3! I'm getting off-topic from my original question, but ... is the first case typically in the negative format 不得? Both examples are negative, wondering if it would get used like that in a positive sense (like .. 我为什么去得?) or does that just turn into the děi pronunciation and positioning e.g. `我得去上班` (or following the original question, 我为什么得去?)

Comment: 1. Yes, you can use it in a positive sense like "A says: B能去，我为什么去不得。 B replies: 我为什么去得, 是因为我有这个资格！" 2. `děi` isn't labeled as "助词" but "动词" in Chinese, so it doesn't belong to case 1/2/3 above. It functions like the **auxiliary verb** must/need in English.

Comment: Note the different meaning of your examples. `我得去上班` I **have to** go to work. `我为什么得去?` Why do I **have to** go there?

Answer (score 1):

Put it in simple way, 得 works as a adverb, or some call it particle word that doesn't have a meaning by itself in Chinese. A adverb (or particle word) is to modify verbs, adjectives or other adverbs.

So the possible usages of 得 should be

verb + 得 + complement.
adj + 得 + complement.
adv + 得 + complement.