# In 虽然练习做 ( ) 很多，但是我还是不懂, should we use 的 or 得？

Tags: grammar, particles

In the following sentence:

> 虽然练习做 ( ) 很多，但是我还是不懂。

We have a small discussion with our teacher. Which one should be used in the bracket and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be '得'

In "做 (得) 很多",  '得' functions as an "(degree/extend) particle" that indicate the degree or extend of the verb.

'很多'(a lot) is the degree or extend of the verb

Example:

"做得多/ 做得少"

- 做 (verb)
- 得 (particle that indicate the degree of the verb)
- 多(a lot); 少(little) [*degree*]

More example:

"跑得快/ 跑得慢"

- 跑(verb)
- 得(particle that indicate the degree of the verb)
- 快(fast) ; 慢(slow) [*degree*]

Some people using 的 instead of 得 in this role because the two words sound similar.

Look at the follow sentences, and you can see 的 and 得 are not interchangeable

> '要做的很多'

- '要做' means 'need to do'
- '要做的' means 'things need to be done'(pronoun)
- '要做的(事)很多' means "a lot (of things) to do"

> '要做得很多'

- 要做= verb
- 得 = (particle that indicate the degree of the verb)
- 很多 (degree)

It  means "need to do a lot"

Answer (score 2):

In this context 得 should be used. It works as a [degree complement](https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/Degree_complement), and takes as a form of "verb + 得 + adjective". The phrase after 得 expresses the degree of the adjective.

So in this case,

> 虽然练习做**得**很多，但是我还是不懂。

, where 得 expresses the degree of "做" is "很多".

You shall also refer to [this question](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/89/%E7%9A%84-%E5%9C%B0-%E5%BE%97-when-do-you-use-which), which explain the difference betwen 的, 得, and 地.

Answer (score 0):

得。

A little trick when I learned "的，地，得" in school.

**"的" follow by a noun,** like "她的妈妈"，"美妙的天空"

**"地" follow by verb**, like "用力地哭", "开心地笑"

"得" f**ollow by terms to describe the "action" or verb in front of the "得"**, like your example： "练习做得很多", "扫得真干净"...

Answer (score 0):

得 is probably ok, but I would use 了 or 过 for this context. It would become 虽然练习做 **了**（or 过）很多，但是我还是不懂。

得 is used for leading a degree complement, while 了 is used for the completion of a verb.

Logically, putting 了 or 过 as a completion is more appropriate I think. The logic is that although you **have done(了)** lots of practices, you still can not get it.