# Can 地 be used in place of 的 as a stylistic choice?

Tags: grammar, writing, particles

Is the use of 地 in the following document correct (some specific samples included below)? I feel like there are many cases where 的 should have been used, but 地 is used instead. The number of such cases has me concerned that I am missing or misunderstanding something important about the language. If that usage is correct, could you please help me understand why?

Otherwise, would this just be a stylistic choice on the part of the author for some effect? Is this usage common, e.g. in some genres of literature, in a certain regional variant, etc?

https://www.luoxia.com/douluo/40631.htm

Some samples from that document:

> 现在地唐三已经快要六岁了。
>
> 村子里唯一地铁匠。
>
> 有一个直径一米左右地木牌
>
> 唐三地家住在圣魂村西侧。

Thank you!

Comment: 的 should be used in all of these example sentences

Comment: For more information as of why, it will suffice to say that 地 is a verbal modifier, and in your examples none of the phrases modified by 地 is a verb. Related: [的-地-得, when do you use which?](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/89)

Comment: Thanks, blackgreen. Any ideas as to why the author of that document chose to use 地 instead of 的?

Comment: At first I thought it was just a bunch of refuses. But given that the book genre is fantasy and this usage of 地 appears deliberate, I'm led to believe it's a stylistic choice, probably to represent the foreignness of the setup/location. Vaguely similar to Japanese mangas using Katakana to represent the speech of some non-human characters. But I can't find a precise pattern in the text you linked: some `的`'s are used correctly...

Comment: Thanks, blackgreen! Appreciate you having looked through some of the text on that page. Please know that your belief that this is a stylistic choice due to the genre is very reassuring to me.

Comment: Any time! I've edited the title of your question, as I feel that's the real focus, and this way hopefully it attracts more targeted answers. Feel free to change it back if you think it twists the essence of your question.

Comment: If blackgreen is right about using 地  as a stylistic choice, all of the examples should be in dialogue, not in narrative. It is like they make Yoda speak in an ungrammatical way in Star Wars

Comment: Ah, updating the title like that is a great idea! Thanks for doing that (and the other edits to the question).

Comment: It is a bit hard for a Pinyin Input Method to pick the correct DE correctly. If the author did not pick the correctly for every DE but rely on IME (being lazy), it ends up in this.

Comment: @TangHo Why would those be only in dialogs? A StylistiC ChoicE CaN BE A StylistiC ChoicE IN WhateveR ParT OF A WritteN TexT.

Comment: @blackgreen monologue would be fine too when the narrative is on the standpoint of a character. Characters in fiction can say any thing, grammatical or not

Comment: Internet novels are usually written very quickly (for instance 5000 characters each day) and full of errors. Also there are many piracy sites and they sometimes add even more errors. As a learner, don't trust internet novels too much. If the novel gets published as a real book, editors will proofread it and such a book will be much safer.

Answer (score 5):

I think the document has simply not been well proofread.  The usage of 地 is not consistent though.  We can see the examples like:

> 没错，唐三***的***父亲唐昊，就是一个铁匠。村子里唯一***地***铁匠。

So, I don't believe it's anything relevant to any dialects or stylistics.  Those are simply the ***errors*** that need to be corrected.

Comment: It's hard to believe that. The errors are too many, and when inputing characters with IME, the first choice is always the correct `的`, as it's statistically more frequent for the pinyin syllable DE. Try that yourself on your keyboard with 唯一的, or whatever else. To type 地 instead of 的 you must choose it explicitly.

Comment: @blackgreen There is also this :"但是，作为这个村子里唯一***的***铁匠" . It is quite inconsistent. I also believe it is a bad IME / bad input habit (no quite sure about his though) / lack of proof reading problem.

Comment: I agree with dan and fefe, If it is a stylistic choice, all the examples should be in dialogue, not in narrative

Comment: @fefe Yeah, that's what I thought.  I'd even thought they might have used some type of "voice input", which causes the 的 and 地 to pop up randomly.  But it's all guess work.